# Need client side browser Javascript example on how to make ADA payments via the Eternl wallet?

Tags: wallet, javascript, payment, eternl

I want to initiate an ADA payment via the Eternl wallet via a Javascript code in my browser based dApp.    I'm hoping I can do this in a manner in the same way Eth devs do it on Ethereum via the Metamask browser.

Can someone point me to the most current client side Javascript example for connecting to a user's Eternl wallet and triggering an ADA payment?  Also, any tutorials or general docs on the subject are greatly appreciated as long as they are not outdated.

Also, if anyone knows of an NFT marketplace or contract that would allow me to query, buy, and sell NFTs from my live auction platform I'm building, please let me know.  I am aware of The JPG Store and NFTify but so far I have been unable to determine if they an API a developer can consume to perform those operations.

Note, if this is not the right forum for Cardano developer questions, please point me to the right forum for that.  I have not had much luck with these questions on the Catalyst and Cardano Discord forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/Hyperion-BT/PicoSwap could be the demo you are looking for.

Hosted here: https://www.hyperion-bt.org/PicoSwap/ (chrome only)

The demo contains example code for creating transactions (with or without smart contracts), signing, and submitting through blockfrost. All using javascript only (with the helios library).

PicoSwap is also a minimal marketplace for NFTs, so might be useable for the second part of your question (preview testnet only)

Comment: will that code also work with the Eternl wallet?

Comment: that's the only wallet I've been testing it with :P

Comment: Thanks.  If you know of a link for a TestNet ADA faucet please let me know.

Comment: You've probably found the faucet link by now, but I'll put it here for reference: https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/tools/faucet

Comment: Hi Christian.  I'm having trouble getting PicoSwap started.  Can you give me some tips?  I posted an issue on the PicoSwap GitHub repo just now with the details.